Creating a voice assistance like Jarvis using Python but PyAudio is not working: "ERROR: Failed to build PyAudio"
When I am trying to install PyAudio package in Python version 3.13.0. the following error is coming:
How can I fix it and why is this error coming?
Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.2 -\> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (PyAudio)

I have tried some ways to fix this error by installing some packages.
Source Code:
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')       #getting details of current voice
# for voice in voices:
engine.setProperty('voice', voices)    # setting up volume level  between 0 and 1
engine.setProperty('rate', 130)


def speak(command):
  engine.say(command)
  engine.runAndWait()

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


# speak("Hello bro can I help you with your query?")

